# Inno Setup define the {tmp} location

Tags: inno-setup

I need to define the `{tmp}` constant (i.e. the automatically generated TEMP location), so that it always remains the same and does not change each time it is run. Ideally setting it to the root of the users TEMP directory, rather than the automatically created subdirectory (e.g. `is-70G7E.tmp`):

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Instead of:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\is-XXXXX.tmp
```

Is this possible and, if so, how could it be done?

To expand on the reason for this, in response to comments below, when using [InnoTools Tray](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=59), it creates multiple entries in the System Tray Notification Area Icons:

[image: System Tray Notifications]

This is because each time it is run, it is run from a different `{tmp}` folder. If I can set this manually myself to be constant and handle the issues of checking for files in use etc it will resolve this issue.

If there is another way to resolve this, then I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. The creation of random subdirectory in `TEMP` is hardcoded. There's no way to change it.

See the [`CreateTempDir` function](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_9/Projects/InstFunc.pas#L243) in Inno Setup source code.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't state why you need it to be constant, but a problem may rise if you use a constant folder. What if the folder or files in it are in use? That's why `{tmp}` varies, and Inno Setup handles it for you.

However, you can use the `{%TEMP}` constant or the `GetTempDir` [function](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_gettempdir) instead, with whichever sub-folder you like as a constant. You may need to handle its creation and deletion though.